# Update libs in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, ubuntu-10.04, libraries

I have issue. I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my machine (I don't want any Unity like, or another dist, because I like Gnome2).

I tried to install Google Chrome, like this:

```
bboy@bboy-laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable 
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
google-chrome-stable: Depends: gconf-service but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.23)
                    Depends: libgconf-2-4 (>= 2.31.1) but it is not going to be stalled
                    Depends: libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5) but 1.4.4-5ubuntu2.1 is to be alled
                    Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be 
                    Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1 is to be 
                    Depends: libnspr4 (>= 1.8.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.12.6) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1 is to be 
                    Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.3.2-1ubuntu3.1 is to be d
E: Broken packages
```

I see older versions libs, and in repo missing new versions.

I tried to add repo for Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10 and others, but I cant resolve the address of the repo.

Also I tried to install this packages manually, but every package has many related dependencies.

Sorry about potato. =)

Comment: what's this about potato?

Comment: This isn't on topic of your question, thought you may be interested in gnome2 alternatives (because I have had the same isse).  Now there are good options that behave similarly, but using on GTK3 (gnome2 is stuck on gtk2, i.e. no updates or fixes coming).  MATE is a DE forked from Gnome2 but has the same issue.  Take a look at "Cinnamon", it has an option to have the dual panels like Gnome2, but has GTK3+, current support, and doesn't require any specific distro.  I have Linux Mint 15 with it on it, works well (and uses apt, like you are probably used to).  [/off-topic comment]

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you want, but you may have better luck with Chromium (which is in the 10.04 apt-get package libraries:

```
 sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```